# How to run code on most recently created sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

We have a spreadsheet where two new sheets are added per week, while two are hidden. The name convention follows something along the lines of "we 12.26.20 details" and "EE +12 Hrs we 12.26.20"

We hide the two sheets from two weeks prior, keep last weeks two sheets visible, and then copy the two sheets that are still visible so we can keep the formatting, delete all the data, and then change the sheet name to coincide with this weeks end date.
There will be 4 sheet visible in total.

I want to create  a macro that does some of this formatting, but I run into the issue of the sheet names changing.
I tried `sName = Sheets(1).Name` and so on, but as we continue to hide the sheets, the number increases and the macro runs for the sheet number that has been hardcoded I presume.

How can I run the code on the sheet that has the higher/newer date?

Comment: You could parse the `Right` 8-most letters of the `Sheet.Name`.

Comment: if the sheets are always just added then you might could use `Sheets.Count` to get the total number of sheets and then only use the two newest ones

Comment: Are your sheets always ordered from oldest to newest ?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes they are. For example. "we 01.04.20 details" , "we 01.11.20 details" , "we 1.18.20 details"

Answer (score 0):

I have understood your problem and my suggestion would be to have some particular timestamps of week number within the sheet. This way, it will help you to loop each sheet and only highest 2 week number sheets should be visible and rest will be set to be hidden.

Secondly, I think you are using previous week's sheet to just copy the formatting. I would be much better if you can have a separate formatting template worksheet in your file, this way you can just refer to this each time instead of copying,pasting and then deleting. 4-5 steps will be eliminated which will ultimately aid in performance.

If you can share your resources then I can have a look and fix the issues.